# Font sizes vastly different cross-browser on Android

Tags: css, mobile, fonts, cross-browser

I am trying to create a mobile version of a simple site but having an issue with vastly different font sizes depending on the browser (I'm testing on Android only right now, and don't have access to an iPhone). In my CSS currently I have the following code, but I have also changed the font size to use percent and pixels with the same results. The first screen shot below shows the page in the Dolphin browser, which apparently uses the Webkit engine. In Maxthon browser, which is also Webkit as far as I can tell, it looks similar. This is much too small to read. The second shot shows it in Chrome. In Firefox, it's somewhere in between these two and is readable. I've seen other posts about fonts rendering differently but never with this drastic a difference. How can this be fixed?

```
html, body {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 1em; 
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have an answer, but please note that if you use `html, body` for a selector. font sizes in it will have an exaggerated effect. For example, with `html, body {font-size: 150%;}`, the font size in the body will be over twice as large as the default instead of one and a half times as large.

Comment: If you're seeing different sizes, and you want a uniform view instead, set a physical dimension as your top level rule. Like `font-size: 0.5cm;` and use `rem` units ("relative em") or percentages everywhere else.

Comment: By top level I assume you mean the html level. I tried this, but got the same results. If this is wrong can you give me the correct code? Thanks. 

html {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

body, p, a {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}